# Metric spaces and continous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, metric-spaces

WTS:Let X, Y be metric spaces. If for every open subset U$\subseteq$Y , $F^{-1}$(U) is open in X then F: X$\rightarrow$Y. F is $\textbf{continuous}$ on X .

Proof: Assume for every open subset U in Y, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in X. Let $\epsilon >0$. Let p $\in X$, and so $f(p) \in Y$. Let $V=N_{\epsilon}(f(p))$ . Then $f^{-1}(V)$ is open, and p$\in f^{-1}(V)$. Hence there exists $\delta>0$ : $N_{\delta}(p)$ $\subset f^{-1}(U)$. Hence we have found  delta which depends on epsilon therefore the proof is complete.

The question I have is why can we assume that V= $N_{\epsilon}(f(p))$ moreover, is the proof correct?

Comment: What is the definition of continuity that you are working with?

Comment: $F: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous at each p$\in X$ if $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta>0$ : whenever $x\in X$ and x$\in N_{\delta}(p)$ then $f(x) \in N_{\epsilon}f(p)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asserting that $f$ is continuous at $p$ means that$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x\in X):d(x,p)<\delta\implies d\bigl(f(x),f(p)\bigr)<\varepsilon.$$Another way of expressing this is: for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that$$f^{-1}\bigl(N_\varepsilon\bigl(f(p)\bigr)\supset N_\delta(p).$$That's why we take $V=N_\varepsilon\bigl(f(p)\bigr)$. And, yes, the proof is correct, except that that $U$ should in fact be a $V$.

Comment: But what if there did not exist an epsilon neighbourhood of f(p)? why can we still consider it?

Comment: How can the set $\left\{y\in Y\,\middle|\,d\bigl(y,f(p)\bigr)<\varepsilon\right\}$ *not* exist?

Comment: How can I formally prove that every element in a metric space has a neighbourhood?

Comment: For each $x\in X$ and for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\{x\in X\,|\,d(y,x)<\varepsilon\}$ is a neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: oh, that's the definition of a neighbourhood. It exists, because it was defined to exist, am I right?

Comment: Yes, it follows from the definition that this set exists.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help